# Severe degradation in Cassandra Write performance with continuous streaming data over time

Tags: cassandra, datastax-enterprise

I notice a severe degradation in Cassandra write performance with continuous writes over time.

I am inserting time series data with time stamp (T) as the column name in a wide column that stores 24 hours worth of data in a single row. 
Streaming data is written from data generator (4 instances, each with 256 threads) inserting data into multiple rows in parallel.
Additionally, data is also inserted into a column family that has indexes over DateType and UUIDType.

CF1:

```
        Col1    |   Col2    |   Col3(DateType)  |   Col(UUIDType4)  |
```

RowKey1

RowKey2

:

:

CF2 (Wide column family):

RowKey1     (T1, V1)    (T2, V3)    (T4, V4) ......

RowKey2     (T1, V1)    (T3, V3)    .....

:

:

The no. of data points inserted/sec decreases over time until no further inserts are possible. The initial performance is of the order of 60000 ops/sec for ~6-8 hours and then it gradually tapers down to 0 ops/sec. Restarting the DataStax_Cassandra_Community_Server on all nodes helps restore the original throughput, but the behaviour is observed again after a few hours.

OS: Windows Server 2008
No.of nodes: 5
Cassandra version: DataStax Community 1.2.3
RAM: 8GB
HeapSize: 3GB
Garbage collector: default settings [ParNewGC]

I also notice a phenomenal increase in the no. of Pending write requests as reported by the OpsCenter (~of magnitude 200,000) when the performance begins to degrade.

I fail to understand what is preventing the write operations to be completed and why do they pile up over time? I do not see anything suspicious in the Cassandra logs.

Has the OS settings got anything to do with this? 
Any suggestions to probe this issue further?

Comment: I would upgrade to the latest 1.2.X release, 1.2.12, and then try your test again.  There have been a lot of bug fixes since 1.2.3

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Bringing your write timeout in line with the new default in 2.0 (of 2s instead of 10s) will help with your write backlog by allowing load shedding to kick in faster: https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/CASSANDRA-6059

Comment: I will try this out and let you know the results

Comment: With the above change, I do not see a phenomenal increase in the no. of pending writes. There is degradation in performance but it does not taper down to 0 inserts/second as before. I have increased the RAM from 8GB to 16GB on every node of the cluster. I plan to do a couple of experiments increasing the HeapSize as well from 3G to maybe 4-6GB.

Comment: I don't recommend second-guessing the default heap size without a specific reason to do so.

Comment: With 4G as Heap size and 1536M as the MaxNewSize, the write performance seems good. The overall RAM utilization is just around 8GB. Would you agree if I said the off heap memory utilization of Cassandra 1.2 is quite poor. The Read performance seems to be abysmal. Reported an issue here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20823184/maximumretryexception-when-reading-data-off-cassandra-using-multiget

Comment: I would not agree with that.

Answer (score 3):

Do you see an increase in pending compactions (nodetool compactionstats)? Or are you seeing blocked flush writers (nodetool tpstats)? I'm guessing you're writing data to Cassandra faster than it can be consumed.

Cassandra won't block on writes, but that doesn't mean that you won't see an increase in the amount of heap used. Pending writes have overhead, as do blocked memtables. In addition, each SSTable has some memory overhead. If compactions fall behind this is magnified. At some point you probably don't have enough headroom in your heap to allocate the objects required for a single write, and you end up spending all your time waiting for an allocation that the GC can't provide.

With increased total capacity, or more IO on the machines consuming the data you would be able to sustain this write rate, but everything indicates you don't have enough capacity to sustain that load over time.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. There are pending compaction tasks averaging around 30 but I have observed peaks at around 80-100 tasks. The flushes pending looks normal peaking at around 4 to 6.The CMS and ParNewGC collection time increases sometimes but I do not see anything abnormal. Also, I have 3GB heap space committed which I believe is what is recommended in the DataStax documentation. 8GB of RAM is definitely on the lower side, trying to get an upgrade! The overall solution, however scales by adding machines but it is the tapering of performance that is bothering.

Comment: Tapering of performance at high load is the hallmark of being under capacity with Cassandra. You need more IO to handle the load you're pushing. If you have appropriate capacity performance will remain constant until you need to add more capacity.

Comment: I believe storing DataStax OpsCenter data is adding to the performance problem. My next course of action would be to upgrade the RAM to 16GB and then increase heap space to 4-6GB incrementally. What's taken me by surprise is the phenomenal increase in the Pending write requests (over 200,000) as against the accepted limit of 100 in the documentation!

Comment: Where do you see a limit of 100 pending writes in the documentation?

Comment: Interesting, not sure where I got this '100' from! "The number of write requests that have arrived into the cluster but are waiting to be handled. During low or moderate write load, you should see 0 pending write operations (or at most a very low number)." is what the documentation says.