# MaximumRetryException when reading data off Cassandra using multiget

Tags: cassandra, hector, astyanax, datastax-enterprise, pycassa

I am inserting time series data with time stamp (T) as the column name in a wide column that stores 24 hours worth of data in a single row. Streaming data is written from data generator (4 instances, each with 256 threads) inserting data into multiple rows in parallel.

CF2 (Wide column family):

RowKey1 (T1, V1) (T2, V3) (T4, V4) ......

RowKey2 (T1, V1) (T3, V3) .....

:

:

I am now attempting to read this data off Cassandra using multiget. The client is written in python and uses pycassa.

When I query 24 hours worth data for a single row key, over 2 million data points are returned. At 4 rowkeys in parallel using multiget, I get the following error:

File "c:\Python27-64bit\lib\site-packages\pycassa-1.9.1-py2.7.egg\pycassa\columnfamily.py", line 772, in multiget
    packed_keys[offset:offset + buffer_size], cp, sp, consistency)

File "c:\Python27-64bit\lib\site-packages\pycassa-1.9.1-py2.7.egg\pycassa\pool.py", line 576, in execute
    return getattr(conn, f)(*args, **kwargs)

File "c:\Python27-64bit\lib\site-packages\pycassa-1.9.1-py2.7.egg\pycassa\pool.py", line 153, in new_f
    return new_f(self, *args, **kwargs)

File "c:\Python27-64bit\lib\site-packages\pycassa-1.9.1-py2.7.egg\pycassa\pool.py", line 153, in new_f
    return new_f(self, *args, **kwargs)

File "c:\Python27-64bit\lib\site-packages\pycassa-1.9.1-py2.7.egg\pycassa\pool.py", line 153, in new_f
    return new_f(self, *args, **kwargs)
  File "c:\Python27-64bit\lib\site-packages\pycassa-1.9.1-py2.7.egg\pycassa\pool.py", line 153, in new_f
    return new_f(self, *args, **kwargs)

File "c:\Python27-64bit\lib\site-packages\pycassa-1.9.1-py2.7.egg\pycassa\pool.py", line 153, in new_f
    return new_f(self, *args, **kwargs)

File "c:\Python27-64bit\lib\site-packages\pycassa-1.9.1-py2.7.egg\pycassa\pool.py", line 148, in new_f
    (self._retry_count, exc.**class**._*name*_, exc))
pycassa.pool.MaximumRetryException: Retried 6 times. Last failure was timeout: timed out

However, previously I was able to get data with 256 rowkeys in parallel. Now, I have increased the density of data (i.e no .of data points within a time range) and the queries fail with this issue.

We tweaked the buffer_size in multiget and found 8 to be the sweet spot.

HeapSize: 6GB

RAM: 16GB

Read Consistency: ONE

Cluster: 5 node

The CPU utilization is less than 20%. Also, I do not see any abnormal patterns in Read throughput, read latency, disk throughput & disk latency as reported by OpsCenter.

I also tried increasing the read_request_timeout_in_ms in Cassandra.yaml to 60000 but in vain. Any other pointers as to why we are getting this exception?
I would expect the query to take a lot of time to retrieve the results, but nonetheless not fail.

Thanks,

VS

Answer (score 3):

(Answer copied from the same question on the pycassa mailing list.)

> Last failure was timeout: timed out

This indicates a client-side timeout, so adjusting `read_request_timeout_in_ms` won't fix this.  Instead, adjust the timeout parameter for your `ConnectionPool`; the default is 0.5 seconds.

For really wide rows, you may also want to experiment with using `xget()` in parallel across multiple threads.  This will distribute the load from your queries a little better and not put such a burden on one coordinator node.

Comment: Using multiget puts enormous amount of load on the coordinator node. We notice a sudden increase in the heap usage before the client crashes. We tried increasing the connectionpool timeout but that doesn't seem to solve the problem. We also tried the multi-threaded implementation of xget(), but multi-threading in python has issues with scaling due to the GIL issue. Reducing the density of data in a given time window helps but we are just unable to read all the data that we write!

Comment: You are probably i/o bound.